# Pasted image from word appears as link to user computer

Tags: javascript, html, image, firefox, ms-word

I have a problem with pasting some images in some editable div.
Most of the time when I paste an image from word i get it in the form of a base64 image string. The problem is that some times when i paste in image i get

```
<img width="309" height="198" src="file:///C:/Users/Robert/AppData/Local/Temp/msohtmlclip1/01/clip_image002.jpg" />
```

As you can see instead of the image string I get the URL to my temp folder, i think this has something to to with the image size but i'm not really sure.

I would also like to mention that i use firefox, but the same think happens in IE.

Is there a way i can get the image to be pasted as a base64 string ?

**Update**
I figured out that this only happens if the document is a .doc not .docx. But i would like to make it work from both types
Thanks alot.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Updated my question, i want to know if there's something i can do to get the image to be pasted as a base64 string

Comment: What are you using to create your page? PHP? MVC? Straight hard coding in HTML and Javascript? You should really upload the file to whatever server the page is going to reside on (or really any other HTML location) instead of hard coding a base64 string as the tag's src property.

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET MVC i'm only hard-coding them at the first upload to the server, after that i decode them and replace the src with the address to the image